# Initializing Angular form with some values that will never be updated - is it bad practice?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms

Let's say we have a person object which interface looks like this:

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

Let's also assume that:

- dateOfBirth property is not an editable one, but user can change name/surname freely
- backend sends/accepts data in this Person format when frontend sends GET/POST requests and this behavior cannot be changed

Taking into consideration the assumptions mentioned above, is it okay to have in an Angular form any controls which values will never be modified?
It is convenient for me to initialize my form value with this.form.setValue(person) and then after user's alterations send it back to backend with something like this.api.post("mockApi/persons", this.form.value, httpOptions), but I'm wondering if that's ok - so is it or is there a better way to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely acceptable as it sticks to the model pattern of the data coming back from the Person, I use this pattern all of the time with patchValue. Just be careful that if you update the person that the api allows the extra fields even thought they are not editable, you would want to delete them in the save function if this is the case. Also if there is not need to have these for editing etc, you cam create partial interfaces for this etc. Just use the things that you would actually update on the server. Hope this helps.